# How to get the id of edges inside traffic island and intuitive tool for comparing simulator results of SUMO

Tags: eclipse, nodes, simulator, sumo

1.If I want to get edge IDs of each in list format(python), which function should I use from sumolib?
I tried looking for it in sumolib site (https://sumo.dlr.de/pydoc/sumolib.net.html, https://sumo.dlr.de/pydoc/sumolib.net.edge.html) but, the following website does not have good explanation. I might have to try every one by my self.

2.Also, is there an easy way to compare result of two separate simulator scenario intuitively? If there are lots of scenarios, should I make my own python code?

[two edges, in yellow box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1cXQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of all edge IDs in a SUMO network you can read the network and then retrieve all edges with the following code:

```
import sumolib
net = sumolib.net.readNet('myNet.net.xml')
edgeIDs = [e.getID() for e in net.getEdges()]
```

To compare simulation runs you can use the visualization tools see for instance https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Tools/Visualization.html#plot_net_dumppy

Comment: I haven't added any pedestrian sidewalk to the edges I've mentioned. If there are no pedestrian connections, on the edges, I guess I'll have to use vertices(or center points) of junctions with tls in it and locate the edges diagonal to it.

Comment: Yes, you can try that although "diagonal" might be hard to detect